# How to properly pass a parameter to a specific action in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes

I'm setting the routes and I would like to pass a parameter to the delete method.

I've tried this which doesn't work:

```
namespace :admin do
    resources :item do
        get 'create_asset'
        delete 'destroy_asset/:asset_id'
    end
    resources :asset
end
```

I've done that, but it doesn't look like the proper solution...

```
delete 'admin/items/:frame_id/destroy-asset/:asset_id' => 'admin/frames#destroy_asset'2, as: :destroy_asset
```

How can I achieve it? I cannot understand where I'm wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, `resources` name must be plural, so `:item` become `:items`, and `:asset` become `:assets`

Now to answer your question, you should nest `assets` inside `items` to keep your routes RESTful.

Try this:

```
namespace :admin do
  resources :items do
    resources :assets
  end
end
```

Which will generate:

```
DELETE    /admin/items/:item_id/assets/:id(.:format)    assets#destroy
```

Update your `assets_controller.rb` to include this before_action:

```
before_action :load_item

...

private
  def load_item
    @item = Item.find(params[:item_id])
    # If your models are namespaced too use this instead
    # @item = Admin::Item.find(params[:item_id])
  end
```

Now you can simply link to the delete action like this:

`<%= link_to 'Destroy', admin_item_asset_path( @item.id, @asset.id ), method: :delete, data: { confirm: 'Are you sure?' } %>`

Comment: Thanks, it looks definitely cleaner! One thing though: I think it should be `@item = Admin::Item.find(params[:item_id])` due to namespace.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I figure it out a different approach.

Keeping this:

```
namespace :admin do
    resources :item do
        get 'create_asset'
        delete 'destroy_asset'
    end
    resources :asset
end
```

it's possibile to pass `asset_id` to `destroy_asset` action as a normal get parameter:

```
<%= link_to 'Destroy', admin_item_destroy_asset_path( @admin_item.id, asset_id: admin_asset.id ), method: :delete, data: { confirm: 'Are you sure?' } %>
```

So instead of

```
admin/items/:item_id/destroy-asset/:asset_id
```

we'll have

```
admin/items/:item_id/destroy-asset?asset_id:XXX
```